# Calling Template during certain conditions XSLT and C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xslt

I am creating a C# application. The application will pass parameters into XSLT file. What I want is to call a certain template based on the parameter selected in a combobox.

I am testing the `<xsl:call-template />` method, and it's only displaying my last template, not the one I'm calling. I have read up on what the call-template does, and still not working. Am I using it correctly?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="lab06.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >    

    <xsl:param name="selectedLanguage">Java</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedUse">Application</xsl:param>
    <xsl:key name="language-by-use" match="language" use="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
    <xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>
    <xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="intendedUseTemp"/>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/" name="intendedUseTemp" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Intended Use</th>
                    <th>Languages</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedUse"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('language-by-use', programming/purpose/intendedUse[. =$selectedUse]/@id)" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            <br />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" name="standardTemp" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Standard</th>
                    <th>Languages</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedStandard"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('language-by-standard', programming/standards/standard[.=$selectedStandard]/@id)" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            <br />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="/" name="languageTemp">
        <html>

            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th >Programming</th>
                        <th >Intended Use</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Standards</th>
                    </tr>


                    <xsl:for-each select="programming/languages/language[name=$selectedLanguage]">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:variable name="intendedUseID" select="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse[@id=$intendedUseID]" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br  />
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                            <td>   <xsl:variable name="standardID" select="standards/standard/@id" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="/programming/standards/standard[@id=$standardID]" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br />
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

UPDATE:

I am trying to pass a parameter into call-template, but its not working. Am i confusing the use of parameters and call-template? Can i pass it into a variable? My plan is to use the `<xsl:if>` to pass parameters from my C# application into XSLT

```
<xsl:param name="selectedLanguage">Java</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="selectedUse">Application</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="selectedBox">languageTemp</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="language-by-use" match="language" use="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
<xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />



<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="$selectedBox"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit upon one of the odd semantic "features" of XSLT.  Normally, an `xsl:template` will either have a `match` attribute or a `name` attribute to indicate when it will be applied.  It is rare, but it can have both, but that means that **either** the `name` or the `match` can trigger the application.

In your case, every template has `match="/"`.  So, on entry, how does XSLT decide which of your templates to choose?  You are expecting it to use the first one, but all of them have equal priority, so the tie-breaking rule in XSLT is to use the **last** one encountered.

**UPDATE:**
Regarding your updated question.  Yes, you can pass parameters into named templates, and it looks like this:

```
<!-- the named template -->
<xsl:template name="xyzzy">
    <xsl:param name="plugh"/>
    <!-- do something here with $plugh -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some-node">
    <-- calling the template named xyzzy -->
    <xsl:call-template name="xyzzy">
        <xsl:with-param name="plugh" select="child-node"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: According to the W3C specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict in this situation the XSLT may actually signal an error rather than pick the last template, so it is probably good practise to avoid having templates of equal priority.

Comment: @TimC - very true, and I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @bjimba 
Thank you. removing the matches seemed to work. another question, I am trying to pass a parameter into <xsl:call-template> , but it keeps erroring, I have included the code in my update, Am i confusing the use of parameters and call-template? Can pass it into a variable?